# fulltext search for dataset

Tags: search, datatable, search-engine, full-text-search

I'd like to implement fulltext search for a datatable ?

are there any .net libraries which support indexing/searching on the fly ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lucene.NET.

Here's a blog post about how I used it in my application.
http://ifdefined.com/blog/post/Full-Text-Search-in-ASPNET-using-LuceneNET.aspx

Comment: thanks for putting the article together

couple of questions 
1) does the index need a disk file folder or can it live in memory alone ? in my case i need to build & search the index on the fly during the lifetime of a particular winform

2) does the search result indicate which field/property of the document it found a match in ? 
e.g. my datatable has the following fields

Key_ID, Description, Date1, Date2, other non-indexed fields

I would like to highlight the column ( & row ) with the text found
is that possible ?

Comment: #1 - You can use the Lucene.NET "RAMDirectory" class.   I don't have any personal experience with it.

#2 - Yes.   You design what identifiers to store in Lucene's index, so that you can relate the results back to your data.

Answer (score 0):

here's a simple extension of DataTable, which is not exactly "fulltext search", but funny and helpful.

```
public static List<DataRow> FullTextSearch(this DataTable dataTable, string[] keywords) 
{ 

var q = dataTable.AsEnumerable().Where<DataRow>(row => keywords.All(keyword =>row.ItemArray.Select(p => p.ToString()).Any<string>(s => s.Contains(keyword)))); 

return q.ToList(); 

}
```